# Detect click on header icons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am very new with react native. I am using a header from [react-native-elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/API/header/) in my app. This is my code

```
<Header
  leftComponent={{ icon: 'menu', color: '#fff' }}
  centerComponent={{ text: 'MY TITLE', style: { color: '#fff' } }} 
  rightComponent={{ icon: 'home', color: '#fff' }}
/>
```

I was not able to found any example on how to detect the clicks on the icons and if possible show an extra view. My goal is to achieve something like this :
[image]
Do you have any example or sample code?

Comment: In the link you passed, it seems you can pass react component (`leftComponent={<MyCustomLeftComponent />}`), so you can handle the click on the component you will pass, can't you?

Comment: I guess you can pass onClick to the component. Something like this, `leftComponent={{ icon: 'menu', color: '#fff', onClick={//your function} }}`

Answer (score 8):

Write : insted of = , onPress will work

```
  <Header 
     leftComponent={ {text:'ok',color: '#fff', onPress: () => this.myFunction()}}
     centerComponent={{ text: 'MY TITLE', style: { color: '#fff' } }}
  />
```

or you can pass your own component like

```
 leftComponent={<MyCustomLeftComponent />}
```

Comment: Can you explain onPress : {this.myFunction} does not work?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `onPress` instead of `onClick`.

```
 <Header
    leftComponent={{ icon: 'menu', color: '#fff' }}
    centerComponent={{ text: 'MY TITLE', style: { color: '#fff' } }} 
    rightComponent={{ icon: 'home', color: '#fff' onPress={() => this.yourFunction} }}
 />
```